# In Spark,According to the mapping table, is there any way to convert an array of strings into the corresponding array of integers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

In Spark, according to the mapping table (String -> Integer), is there any way to convert an array of strings into the corresponding array of integers?

Ex: In Spark, There are 500 million arrays,

```
Array String 1 : ['TOM','White','Black'] 
Array String 2 : ['BCD','TTTT','Black']
.....
```

Mapping Table： [BCD -> 1, White -> 2,Black -> 3, TTT -> 4 ,TOM ->5, ...]  (one million).

Result:

```
Array Integer 1 : [5,2,3]
Array Integer 2 : [1,4,1]
....
```

Comment: Is the mapping table also rdd/dataframe or just a Map?

Comment: Sure, but try to include the code you are testing and add the Scala tag to receive more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to explode the array column, join with the mapping table, then group back again:

```
scala> val df = Seq(1 -> Array("TOM","White","Black"),
     |              2 -> Array("BCD","TTTT","Black")).toDF("id", "vals")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, vals: array<string>]

scala> df.show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|               vals|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|[TOM, White, Black]|
|  2| [BCD, TTTT, Black]|
+---+-------------------+

scala> val mapping = Seq("BCD" -> 1, "White" -> 2, "Black" -> 3, "TTTT" -> 4, "TOM" -> 5).toDF("k", "v")
mapping: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [str: string, ind: int]

scala> mapping.show()
+-----+--+
|    k| v|
+-----+--+
|  BCD| 1|
|White| 2|
|Black| 3|
| TTTT| 4|
|  TOM| 5|
+-----+--+

scala> df
     |  .select($"id", posexplode($"vals") as Seq("pos", "val")).alias("df_exp")
     |  .join(mapping as "mapping", $"df_exp.val" === $"mapping.k")
     |  .repartition($"id")
     |  .sortWithinPartitions($"pos")
     |  .groupBy($"id")
     |  .agg(collect_list($"v") as "mapped")
     |  .show()
+---+---------+
| id|   mapped|
+---+---------+
|  1|[5, 2, 3]|
|  2|[1, 4, 3]|
+---+---------+
```

Because joining datasets shuffles the data and the consecutive grouping of distributed data is non-deterministic, `posexplode()` is used to obtain an additional column containing the original position of each value in its array and the data is first repartitioned on `id` and then sorted within each partition.

If using Spark < 2.1.0, `monotonically_increasing_id()` can be used instead.

In SQL it should be something like:

```sql
WITH df_exp AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    posexplode(vals) AS (pos, val)
  FROM df
)
SELECT
  id,
  collect_list(v) AS mapped
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    v
  FROM df_exp
  JOIN mapping
  ON val = k
  DISTRIBUTE BY id
  SORT BY pos ASC
) 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thank you . but My data set is very large, will it be slow to process?  The array contains more than 500 values，and  
thetable contains more than 500 million records.

Comment: Joining huge distributed datasets is never lightning fast. But there are ways to optimise the operation. E.g., repartitioning the exploded table by the `val` column and asking Spark to use [sort-merge joins](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/sort-merge-join-spark-sql/read).